# Image whit feed rss in php page

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

[Feed RSS]
hello i have a blog and I created this rss file where I put the link to the photos, but with the rss reader I can not view them. Where am I wrong?

```
    <? php
$ connection = mysql_connect ( "xxx ", " xxx" , "xxx ");
mysql_select_db ( "xxx ", $ connection ) ;
$ selezionedati = "SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20" ;
$ query = mysql_query ($ selezionedati ) or die ( mysql_error ());

header (" Content-type: text / xml ");

echo (" <rss version=\"2.0\"> ");
echo (" <channel> ");
echo (" <title> People </ title >") ;
echo (" <link> http://espanici/archivio.php </ link >") ;
echo (" <description> people < / description> ");
echo " <copyright> Copyright 2013 < / copyright > \ n";
echo " <docs> http://espanici < / docs > \ n";
echo " <managingEditor> espanici ( emanuele ) </ managingEditor > \ n";
echo " <webMaster> espanici.com ( emanuele ) </ webMaster > \ n";
echo (" <language> IT- en </ language >") ;
while ($ array = mysql_fetch_array ( $ query )) {
extract ( $ array ) ;
echo " <item>
<title> $ name </ title>
<link> http://espanici/tabella.php?id = $ id </ link>
<description> $ name < / description>
<image>
<link> http://espanici/tabella.php?id = $ id / </ link>
<url> http://espanici/ $ location < / url >
<title> $ name </ title>
</ image>
</ item > " ;
}
echo " < / channel > </ rss >" ;
? >
```

notifications insertion work. When I click on the link opens the exact card, but I wanted to insert photos. I used that code which refers to the correct link of the photo, but the app does not see it.
this is the page http://espanici.altervista.org/antonio/fedd.php this is the url

where $location is the path for image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by entering the following code.

```
<description><![CDATA[<img src=\"http://espanici/$location\" width=\"57\" height=\"57\" />]]></description>
```