# Dynamically adding different images to my rss feed

Tags: php, rss

Hellow there im php newbie by the way!

my problem is i need to display in my rss feed different images that are on different pages in my website and all images are stored on my server at some folder called "allimages" and those pages are pulled from my database,i searched and searched almost everywhere but i ddnt find solution related to this issue [except here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274086/image-whit-feed-rss-in-php-page) in SO.I tried to modified to my own but it ddnt work where im wrong!? any help will be appreciated

thanx.

below is the code

```
    <?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$connection = mysql_connect( "------", "-----", "-----");
mysql_select_db("-------", $connection);
$selezionedati = "SELECT * FROM NEWSPAGES ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20";
$query = mysql_query($selezionedati ) or die(mysql_error());

echo (" <rss version=\"2.0\"> ");
echo (" <channel> ");
echo (" <title>People</title>");
echo (" <link>http://tabata.com</link>");
echo (" <description>tabata</description> ");
echo " <copyright>Copyright 2013</copyright> \ n";
echo " <managingEditor>tabata(sun)</managingEditor> \ n";
echo " <webMaster>tabata.com (sun)</webMaster> \ n";
echo (" <language>IT- en</language>");
while($array = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
extract($array);
echo "<item>
<title>$title</title>
<link>http://tabata.com/news.php?page=$id</link>
<description><![CDATA[<img src=\"http://tabata.com/$allimages\" width=\"57\" height=\"57\" />]]>$description</description>
<image>
<link>http://tabata.com/news.php?page=$id</link>
<url>http://tabata.com/$allimages</url>
<title>$title</title>
</image>
</item>";
}
echo " </channel> </rss>" ;
?>
```

Comment: and where did you define `$allimages` ?

Comment: @meda where should i define?

Comment: oh I didnt notice you extract the array, have you tried printing the array? `var_dump($array)`

Comment: @meda i think we are nearly to reach,it doesnt show up anything in rss feed but when i check to source code it show up something like   </item>array(36) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [2]=>
  string(44) "Wasanii wa kibongo na shoo za sebuleni ulaya"
  ["name"]=>
  string(44) "Wasanii wa kibongo na shoo za sebuleni ulaya"
  [3]=>
  string(7197) "<div>
<p><img alt="" height="151" src="/userfiles/23.jpg" width="300" />\</p>
......................................................
</div>

Comment: thats what you need to get working before attempting to create RSS, I suggest you to run that query directly, if that works it mean PHP has trouble

Comment: @meda ok let me check first bout that then i will let u know

Comment: oh wait, you edited your comment, you are actually getting data, now the problem is you have all that html markup (`<div> <p><img alt="" height="151" src="/userfiles/23.jpg" width="300" />\</p>`) , cant you just store the image name

Comment: @meda hellow there! still i ddnt find the solution!,and im using no as image name

Comment: have a look at xml source  [here](http://www.tabelltz.com/2nd.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add different images in my rss feed using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115259/how-to-add-different-images-in-my-rss-feed-using-php)