# how to add different images in my rss feed using php

Tags: php, rss

i want to add images dynamically in my rss feed but its only showing thumbs then it disappear see the sample [here](http://www.tabelltz.com/2nd.php)

my images are stored on my server at a folder called "allimages" and all pages are retrieved from mysql database.
where em i wrong!!!?

Any help ll be appreciated
 thaanx
below is my code

```
 <?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$connection = mysql_connect( "------", "-----", "-----");
mysql_select_db("-------", $connection);
$sundo = "SELECT * FROM NEWSPAGES ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20";
$query = mysql_query($sundo ) or die(mysql_error());

echo (" <rss version=\"2.0\"> ");
echo (" <channel> ");
echo (" <title>People</title>");
echo (" <link>http://tabata.com</link>");
echo (" <description>tabata</description> ");
echo " <copyright>Copyright 2013</copyright> \ n";
echo " <managingEditor>tabata(sun)</managingEditor> \ n";
echo " <webMaster>tabata.com (sun)</webMaster> \ n";
echo (" <language>IT- en</language>");
while($array = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
extract($array);
echo "<item>
<title>$title</title>
<link>http://tabata.com/news.php?page=$id</link>
<description><![CDATA[<img src=\"http://tabata.com/$allimages\" width=\"57\" height=\"57\" />]]>$description</description>
<image>
<link>http://tabata.com/news.php?page=$id</link>
<url>http://tabata.com/$allimages</url>
<title>$title</title>
</image>
</item>";
}
echo " </channel> </rss>" ;
```

?>

Comment: You're dumping arbitrary text into XML. If ANY of that text contains html or xml metacharacters, especially `<` and `>`, you'll be introducing xml syntax errors. Plus, `\ n` is pointless. it's not a line break. it's an escaped "space" followed by an `n`

Comment: @marc that code works perfectly for me xept displaying images!

Answer (score 0):

Save image names/full url in you database, create a column of images let say `images`. Then in you while loop you can get images like `$array['images']`.
Like 
`<image>
...
<url>http://tabata.com/$array['images']</url>
...
</image>`

Like for page `http://tabelltz.com/news.php?page=31` you image column should have img name `27.jpg`
and url like 
`<url>http://tabata.com/userfiles/$images</url>` 
I use `$images` as you're using `extract($array);`
Better if you don't use `extract($array);`

Comment: i tried but it givin me an error! or can you make me correct may be on $array['images'] on while loop to format it thru my code above!?

Comment: Did you add `images` column in your database that contain images name?

Comment: yes i created a column named `images`but its recomended not to store images direct to a database its better to use image path,so how can i add images name in `images` column?

Comment: Check in my answer as I said, if you've page http://tabelltz.com/news.php?page=31 has image http://tabelltz.com/userfiles/27.jpg then you can only save 27.jpg in image column of page 31 row. And when echo link you use like `<url>http://tabata.com/userfiles/$images</url>` in your for loop

Comment: i got some stuck on this qn [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315423/correction-of-sending-image-to-my-folder-and-image-path-to-my-database-related-t) on image path,image upload

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code becomes quite unreadable because you use `SELECT *` and `extract()`.
You could better replace them with `SELECT field1, field2, etc` and I suggest avoiding the `extract()` function all-time, you suggest you'd use something like `$field1 = $array['field1']`.

Then it should be easier to find out if the field `allimages` exists in your query result. Test each step of the process with `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to check if a value contains the expected result.

Comment: where should i define `$field1 = $array['field1']`

Comment: Between the `while`-part, thus:

Comment: `while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $title = $array['title'];
  $id = $array['ID'];
  $description = $array['description'];
  $allimages = $array['allimages'];

  echo "<item>\n";
  echo "<title>$title</title\n";
  echo "<description>" . htmlentities("<img src=\"http://tabata.com/$allimages\" />$description") . "</description>\n";
  echo "More goes here...";
}`

Of course, the above requires a column named 'allimages' to exist in your database, containing something like `allimages/image.jpg`. 
Further, @marc-b was indeed correct, see example.